# Making the XMLHttpRequest code more elegant

Tags: ajax

I'm just wading into the world of AJAX. It looks to me like this section of code is going to be in almost every function that I write:

```
var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
} else {  
    // code for IE6, IE5
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
```

What I'm wondering is if there is a way to set this off into a separate file with a getter function and then include this file in my code. Something like:

```
include('xmlhttp');
var xmlhttp = get_xmlhttp();
```

Just wondering. Not the world's most important question, but if anyone has done something like this, I'd appreciate any suggestions. Thanks!

Comment: I would personally just use jquery.

Comment: Whoever gave me a -1 for asking a question should be ashamed of themselves.

Comment: @usr55410: Do you actually support IE5 and IE6? If you don't, then just use `XMLHttpRequest`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not simply create e.g. `get_xmlhttp` function in separete file? Then include your file (maybe there you can add more useful function) where you think it's needed, so basically you need something like this:

```
/* 
 * This function is used to make AJAX call.
 * You can improve it by adding parameters (e.g. destination, custom data, etc)
 *
 * Filename: js/helper.js
 */
function get_xmlhttp() { 

    var xmlhttp;

    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {  
        // code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }

    return xmlhttp;

}
```

And later, to include JavaScript file, you simply add:

> `<script src="js/helper.js"></script>`